# Inequality involving absolute values: $|x + 3| + |2x + 5| > |x^2 - 4|$

Tags: inequality

$$|x + 3| + |2x + 5| > |x^2 - 4|$$

I have tried to solve this problem but I don't know what would be the best way to solve it. I tried to apply the triangular inequality, but I have not been able to solve it. Any idea?

Comment: Divide the real line into $(-\infty, -3], (-3,-2.5], (-2.5,2]$ and $2, \infty)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Shouldn't there be further partitioning to intervals $[-2,2]$ and $(-2.5,-2]$?

Comment: You are right. I was careless. @Keen-ameteur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While we know several properties of the absolute value, the direct method is to work with it's definition:

$$\vert x\vert=\begin{cases}x& x\geq 0 \\ -x & x<0 \end{cases} $$

The way to work with this definition is to check where every term inside each absolute value is greater or equal to zero and where it is less then zero. i.e:

$$ x+3\geq 0 \quad \Longleftrightarrow x\geq -3 $$
$$ 2x+5\geq 0 \quad \Longleftrightarrow x\geq -\frac{5}{2} $$
$$ x^2-4\geq 0 \quad \Longleftrightarrow  x\geq2 \; \text{or} \; x\leq -2 $$

This almost corresponds to intervals Kavi Rama Murthy wrote: 
$$ (-\infty,-3], \quad (-3,-2.5], \quad (-2.5,-2], \quad (-2,2] \quad \text{and} \quad (2,\infty) $$
Such that for $x$ in each interval you know how to write the inequality without the absolute value and find possible additional conditions for it to hold. For example, in the interval $(-2,2]$ the inequality translates to:

$$ x+3 +2x+5 > -(x^2-4) \Longleftrightarrow x^2+3x+4>0 $$

And the right hand inequality always holds, thus the original inequality holds when $x\in (-2,2]$. Similar analysis on the other intervals will give you when the original inequality holds.